# Polymer Firebase : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInWithPopup' of undefined

Tags: web, firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication

I'm a newbie with Polymer and Firebase, i am practicing with the two technologies. I am trying to implement firebase-auth for application authentication but i go a "Cannot read property 'signInWithPopup' of undefined" error.

i have this code :

```
<paper-toolbar>
  <span class="title">Sample!</span>
  <paper-icon-button
    icon="[[statusIcon(signedIn)]]"
    on-tap="processAuth">
  </paper-icon-button>
</paper-toolbar>
<firebase-auth
  id="auth"
  app-name="emotions"
  provider="google"
  signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
  user="{{user}}">
</firebase-auth>
```

and the script for processAuth

```
processAuth: function() {
    this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
}
```

and the following components were imported already:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">
```

Did i missed something?

Sorry for this very noob question.

Comment: The error is telling you that `this.$.auth` is undefined. Are the `paper-toolbar` and `firebase-auth` tags inside of the `template` tag in you Polymer element? The method you are using is the correct way for accessing elements nested in a Polymer element.

Comment: "firebase-auth.html" is already imported in "polymerfire.html". No need to import it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have initialize `firebase-app` with the same `app-name` before you use `firebase-auth`

Comment: how do we do that though?

Answer (score -2):

Try using `document.getElementById('auth')` instead of `this.$.auth`.

It seems for me, that `this.$.auth` is trying to find an `#auth` inside `paper-icon-button`, which is not there.
Check `console.log(this)` from `processAuth` to verify where `this` is pointing at.

Comment: `document.getElementById('auth')` is for accessing items outside of a Polymer element.